# Anybody got an Actionscript 3 Youtube API / wrapper?

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-api

Google / Youtube has an API for Youtube for javascript and Actionscript 2.

Unfortunately this API is not compatible with Actionscript 3 without a wrapper - which google does not themselves provide.

Has anybody got an actionscript 3 wrapper they can make available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY! YouTube's official API changed from AS2 to AS3

> http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html
>
> Note: This documentation was updated
> in October 2009 to explain how to use
> AS3 rather than ActionScript 2.0
> (AS2).

Answer (score 3):

[as3youtubelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3youtubelib/)

Answer (score 3):

as3youtubelib is only for the API itself - for searching videos etc.

I wanted a wrapper for the youtube video player itself.

http://code.google.com/p/youtubechromelesswrapper-as3/  is a new API that allows you to embed in Flash/Flex and uses the Javascript API (via ExternalInterface) to control the movie within Flash. It doesn't have any control buttons, but has the YouTube logo.

Answer (score 1):

or this: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/tubeloc.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this wrapper which doesn't have volume issues and multiple instances problems as the one on YouTube: http://www.ovidiudiac.ro/blog/?p=70

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is an AS3 WRAPPER HERE 
http://flashden.net/item/as3-youtube-wrapper-full-xml-site/21685